# how to set a value if there is no char to check

Tags: java, char, set

So basically I am asking a user to type a line. It only accepts the first 10 characters. If enter is pressed it will just set that whole line to false.

Then I want to set an array to true if the char is #, otherwise everything else will be false. So I tried this

```
boolean[][] world = new boolean [8][10];

for(int i = 0; i< world.length; i++){
String Temp = userinput.nextLine();
for(int j = 0; j <world[i].length; j++){

if( temp.equals("")){
world[i][j] = false;

}
Else if( temp.charAt(j) == 35){
world[i][j] = true;
}
else { 
world[i][j] = false;
}
}
}
```

Then there would be a print method containing this to print out the array, when it is true it should print a # otherwise it will print .

```
for(int i = 0; i< world.length; i++){
for(int j = 0; j <world[i].length; j++){
if(world[i][j] = true){
System.out.print("#");
}
else{
System.out.print(".");
}
```

the only problem is if a user does not enter at least 10 characters it will give an error because its not possible to do charAt nothing.
Here is an example of what a userinput might look like and what it should do.
if userinputs this

```
#..jh##pop#jfhjdfh#
..fjd#jdjk#kkjnjk

dklsd#klmsfkdfmsdf
#.d.sd
##########
fjdfgk#3fdlksf
l#ldflfsdfl#dflsdf
```

it should print out like this

```
#....##...
.....#....
..........
.....#....
#.........
##########
......#...
.#........
```

So things like that 5th line where the user entered #.d.sd is the only problem because it does not have atleast 10 characters. What it should do is like what was printed above, just fill those spots in with "."
If anyone knows how I can solve this that would be great.

Comment: Not 100% sure I get what you want but could it be: if(world[i][j] = true){System.out.print(world[i][j]); instead of: if(world[i][j] = true){
System.out.print("#");

Comment: `if(world[i][j] = true)` is incorrect. It assigns a value to word[i][j] rather than checking whether its value is true. You should never compare a boolean value to true or false, just use the value itself, since it IS a boolean. Thus `if ( word[i][j] ){...}` or to check for false, `if ( !word[i][j] ) {   }` This avoids the problem of using `=` when you really meant `==`

Answer (score 1):

You need a bounds check on your String `temp`, like

```
if( temp.equals("")){
world[i][j] = false;
}
else if (temp.length() <= j) { // Bounds check
  world[i][j] = false
}
Else if( temp.charAt(j) == 35){
world[i][j] = true;
}
else { 
world[i][j] = false;
}
```

Comment: Oh yea I didn't even think of that. Wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add this condition to this line

`if(temp.equals("") || temp.length()<10){
   world[i][j] = false;
   }`